# Execute a service during a specific period of time

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, thinkpad

Good morning,
I have a script that activates backlight on my laptop keyboard when I type.
I set a service that keeps the script active during all the day, but now I’d like to do a different thing.
Is it possible to set systemctl in order to keep the service active only during night? (Ex 9pm-7am) So:

1. if system boots during this period service will be executed, otherwise if it boots during a different period it won’t.
2. If system is active at 8pm the service will be started, then at 7am it will be stopped.
3. If the service is active and laptop goes in sleep mode and I reopen it for example in the afternoon service should stop.

I set a crontab but it works only for the second point. I don’t know yet if it works also for the third point.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "`@reboot`" in your `crontab`.
2. 8PM `cron` job to start service if needed, also queue an `at` job for `0700` to stop it. Read `man at`
3. Install the `pm-tools` package, read `dpkg -L pm-tools` to find out how to execute a script at Suspend/Resume/Hibernate/Resume.